# Kivy 1.8.x Python3 support for Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, python-3.3, kivy

I just started getting involved with Kivy.  I have used the prebuilt Windows binary package that supports Python 3. However, I want to be able to use Kivy with Python 3 on Ubuntu.  Has this been done, and if so, how do I use Kivy and Python 3 on Ubuntu.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: This belongs on the kivy usergroup or IRC channel, not here. In particular, kivy states that 1.8.0 supports python3. So unless you have specific issues and you show what you tried this doesn't belong here.

Answer (score 2):

I use this script to install Python 3 Kivy 1.8 on Ubuntu 12.04 https://github.com/brousch/kivy-installer/tree/master/ubuntu/1204/python33